# How to save dates in Firestore timestamp field from a cloud function REST API?

Tags: javascript, firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

New to Google Cloud Functions and REST APIs.

I am programming a REST API Google Cloud Function to send data from another app to Firestore database. I am having difficulties saving the date in a timestamp field in Firestore. I tried a few approaches like this one:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const express = require("express");


  const idBubble = req.body.idBubble;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const nombre = req.body.nombre;
  const apellidos = req.body.apellidos;
  const total = req.body.total;

  const fechaCompra = req.body.fechaCompra;
  console.log("fechaCompra:", fechaCompra);

  const parsedDate = new Date(fechaCompra);
  console.log("parsedDate:", parsedDate);

  const timestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(parsedDate.getTime());
  console.log("timestamp:", timestamp);

  const promotoresRef = db.collection("promotores").doc(idBubble);
  const ventasData = {
    nombre: nombre,
    apellidos: apellidos,
    total: total,
    fechaCompra: timestamp,
  };
```

I also tried this approach:

```
const idBubble = req.body.idBubble;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const nombre = req.body.nombre;
  const apellidos = req.body.apellidos;
  const total = req.body.total;
  const fechaCompra = req.body.fechaCompra;
  const fechaConvertida = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(fechaCompra));

  const promotoresRef = db.collection("promotores").doc(idBubble);
  const ventasData = {
    nombre: nombre,
    apellidos: apellidos,
    total: total,
    fechaConvertida: fechaConvertida,
  };
```

In the console fechaCompra and fechaConvertida are getting the right format of the date, ISO 8601. In both aproaches the issue is with `.fromMillis` or `fromDate`.

The console error:

```
fecha compra: 2023-09-15T15:45:30.000Z
>  C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\firebase-api\functions\index.js:42
>    const fechaConvertida = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(fechaCompra));
>                                                      ^
>
>  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fromDate')
>      at C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\firebase-api\functions\index.js:42:53
>      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\firebase-api\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>      at next (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\firebase-api\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
>      at isAuthenticatedWithApiToken (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\firebase-api\functions\index.js:29:10)
>      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\firebase-api\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>      at next (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\firebase-api\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
>      at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\firebase-api\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3) 
>      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\firebase-api\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>      at C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\firebase-api\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
>      at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\firebase-api\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
>
>  Node.js v18.17.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

Step 1 `const {Timestamp} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");`
Step 2 `const fechaISOcompra = req.body.fechaISOcompra;`
Step 3 `const fechaCompra = Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(fechaISOcompra));`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).